# On the properties of irrational number

Tags: arithmetic

Let $a$ is an irrational number. Then prove or disprove that 
$$a+a^2$$ is irrational number.

Comment: Are you looking to prove this or disprove this?

Comment: I could not prove it and also could not find an example for disprove it

Comment: Why negative vote?

Comment: What if we force $a+a^2$ to be some nice rational number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a^2+a = \frac{1}{2} \implies a \in \{ \frac{1}{2}(-1 \pm \sqrt{3}) \}$, both irrational.

Comment: Oh yes. thank you. So there exists very examples

Comment: Yes.  Any $q in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $1+4q$ is not the square of a rational number produces an irrational $a$.  This is just the quadratic formula...  (For a negative instance, $q = -1/4$ forces $a = -1/2$.)